# Is this proof concerning field axioms valid?

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

> If $r$ is a rational number and $x$ irrational, prove $r + x$ and $rx$ are irrational.

First, suppose

$$\exists p, q \in \Bbb N : {p \over q} = r + x$$

This is equivalent to $${p \over q} - {p_{0} \over q_{0}} = x$$

Also equivalent to $${pq_{0} - p_{0}q \over qq_{0}} = x$$

Since the numerator is an element of $\Bbb N$, then $p \over q$ is rational. But $x$ is irrational, a contradiction. Thus $r + x$ is irrational.

To solve the latter exercise, suppose

$$\exists p, q \in F : {p \over q} = {p_{0}\over q_{0}}x$$

Then we can say

$${p \over qp_{0}} = {1\over q_{0}}x = 1$$

because of the multiplicative inverse axiom. Hence $x = q_{0}$. But an irrational number cannot equal a natural number, and this is a contradiction. Hence $rx$ is irrational.

Comment: You've got it. If the additive inverse is a member of the field, we can add it to any other member without 'escaping' the field. EDIT: regarding the second part, I'm not sure how you got $q_0^{-1}x=1$, but if we multiply by $q_0$ that should suffice.

Comment: @JonathanY. Since the integers are a subset of the rationals, we can use the additive inverse property to be included under addition. Correct?

Comment: @JonathanY. I divided by $p_{0}$ on each side.

Comment: For the addition, instead of $s-t$ you can use $s+(-t)$. For the multiplication, there is a slip, should conclude $x=\frac{pq_0}{qp_0}$.

Comment: True, I can subtract the rationals and assume "0" is rational - but since it is irrational in this context, the whole thing is a contradiction.

Comment: Short version of the technical part: if $r$ and $r+x$ are rational, then $(r+x)-r$ is rational.

Comment: And since addition is associative, I suppose that leads to a contradiction. Thanks @Hurkyl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma:** If $s, t$ are rational, then $-t$, $s+t$, and $st$ are rational. Consequently, $s+(-t)$ is rational.

**Proof:** If $t=\frac{c}{d}$, where $c$ and $d$ are integers, then $-t=\frac{-c}{d}$.

If furthermore $s=\frac{a}{b}$ then $s+t=\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$ and $st=\frac{ac}{bd}$.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is correct, but in the second part your conclusion
$$\frac x{q_0}=1$$ is complete nonsense (comes from nothing). If $r,x$ are rationals then $rx$ being a rational should certainly not imply $x$ is an integer. Up to $${p \over qp_{0}} = {1\over q_{0}}x$$ you are fine so multiply by $q_0$ we get $${{pq_0} \over qp_{0}}=x$$